# array in prepared statement inside where in clause

Tags: c++, mysql

```
prep_stmt = con->prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table WHERE customers in ( ? ) and alive = ?");
prep_stmt->setString(1,customer_string);
prep_stmt->setInt(2,1);
res = prep_stmt->executeQuery();
```

Here the customer_string is "12,1,34,67,45,14"
When I pass it as a String it always returns a single row, takes the first value only 12.

The sql statement prepared is:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE customers in ( "12,1,34,67,45,14" ) and alive = 1
```

but I want sql statement to be prepared as:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE customers in (12,1,34,67,45,14 ) and alive = 1
```

What is the easiest way to achieve the same in C++?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are using the MySQL C++ Connector. Unfortunately it seems that it is not possible to pass array as parameter of prepared statement using this API:

> Connector/C++ does not support the following JDBC standard data types: ARRAY, BLOB, CLOB, DISTINCT, FLOAT, OTHER, REF, STRUCT.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-usage-notes.html

You can place the value into the query directly by concatenating strings. Be VERY careful to not introduce SQL injection vulnerability. Alternatively use some other API.

Comment: "You can place the value into the query directly by concatenating strings." this makes back to string only ...just the same as customer_string is "12,1,34,67,45,14"